# How to transfer minecraft worlds from iPad to iPad

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I tried using Internet Explorer and it did not work. I am wondering if it is because of my iPad pro. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use iExplorer, not Internet Explorer.  On your computer, download iExplorer and plug in the first iPad (the one the world you want is on).

Open iExplorer, and select your iPad. Look at the left side of the screen, and click "applications". Then click Documents, Games, and then Com.Mojang, and you should see something like "worlds" or "saves". Copy the files in that folder to your desktop (don't delete the ones on the iPad, just copy and move.

Now, unplug the first iPad and plug in the second.  Find the world/save folder on this iPad, and copy the files you saved to the desktop into that folder.  Now you can unplug the second iPad, open minecraft, and the worlds should be there.